# Black bar appears under image on focus HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**Issue:** When you click our logo a black bar appears underneath it in both firefox and chrome. If you hold the click on the logo it'll stay.

**Below is some of the code I have tried to remove the black bar on focus:**

```
a:active, a:focus { 
 outline: none; 
}
a {
outline: none;
}
:focus {
outline:none;
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
border:0;
}
a img {outline : none;}
img {border : 0;}
```

Can someone tell me what is causing the black bar?

Comment: Even while holding the click on the australian government logo? It could be specific to windows browsers.

Comment: @JakeGould I see it. Looking for a fix.

Comment: That's correct. It's a weird problem.

Comment: @sephiith very wierd I've been looking at this for like 10 mins and have no clue what it is.

Comment: @sephiith Reduce the use of !important statements in your css, and this will make it easier for you in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because, on line 45 of screen.css, you have the rule saying "background-color: #000 !important;" which is affecting a.coa-link (Your rule is set to affect a:focus, a:active, amongst others. This is why it only occurs when you click/click-hold on the link [focussing on the element.])

If you add to line 35 of style.css:

```
#header a.coa-link { clear: both; /* YOUR EXISTING CODE */
    background-color: transparent !important; /* NEW LINE OF CODE */ }
```

Then your issue will not occur anymore.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the background-color for `.coa-link` class, to `rgb(43,66,114)` which is the background-color set to your body element.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it is a very weird issue, but a workaround is to add a div around the image:

```
<a class="coa-link" href="/" title="Home">
<div>
<img src="/files/2012/07/AC-banner-white-test7.png" alt="">
</div>
</a>
```

It worked for me in the chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have *focus* styles implemented for `<a>` tags.  The reason it's shown as a black bar is because the `<a>` that surrounds the logo image does not have `display: block;` in the CSS.  If it did have `display: block`, the entire header would have a black background.

[image]

Another problem is that there is an `!important` tag in there. Booo.

You need to add the following style to fix the black bar in your logo link:

```
#header .coa-link a {
    display: block;
}

#header .coa-link a:focus,
#header .coa-link a:active, {
    background: transparent!important;
}
```

I would never ever suggest using the `!important` declaration in CSS, but as someone has already added it in, you need to override it.  Ideally remove the `!important` tag that's shown in the attached image, and then you won't need it in the fix.